# Add - Ons for experimental effects [VST, AU]

Tags: sound-effects, effects, vst, plugins, experimental

I'm searching for VST or AU plugins (best if it's free) for getting experimental effects. By experimental I mean uncommon results as opposed to flangers, phasers, reverbs, bit crushers that are the most "classic" effects we can get with most of the audio applications/gears.

[Illformed - Glitch](http://illformed.org/) plugin is a good one but I already have it and it's getting pretty old, so any new ones...?

Thanks,

Comment: Using traditional effects in untraditional ways is a time-honored technique for creating new sounds. With just delay, EQ, and distortion plug-ins and some creative signal routing you may be able to get all kinds of strange things to happen. I'm old enough that bit crushers are new-fangled doo-dads to me, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of graphical programming languages that allow you to build completely new DSP effects, without actually needing to write program code.

Max/MSP (together with PureData, its free sibling) is certainly the most renowned of these. I wouldn't be too sure if VST exporting works, but it seems [in principle possible](https://cycling74.com/wiki/index.php?title=Gen_Code_Export_VST). Still, these programs are definitely more suited for standalone running / live tweaking.

Another such system was SynthMaker, which I actually liked a lot (though I stopped using it because it's Windows-only). This can export VSTs very easily. It has now been merged into the [FlowStone](http://www.dsprobotics.com/) robotics coding system, but I believe is still capable of designing simple VST plugins.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of cool granular plugs on this site: http://www.michaelnorris.info/software

https://valhalladsp.com/ also has a couple neat freebies

Answer (score 0):

Check out Audacity - its a standalone DAW - a Free piece of software where the community has written lots of add ins.  There is a published effect coding feature that allows you to design and build your own effects.
One of the drawbacks is that you cannot implement, or change parameters on, an effect real time.  Ive been a user for 7 years and find it easy to use for post edit work.

Comment: can you create vst plugins?